# Setting background of a list item

Tags: android, listview, background, onitemclicklistener

When I click on an item of a listView, the background of an other item than I have clicked is changed. If I click on the first one, the background of that and of the last item of the ListView is changing. If I scroll down and click on an item, the item after the one I clicked changes its color. What can I do to just change the selected item's background?

XML:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lvPlace"/>
```

Java:

```
lvPlace=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPlace);
lvPlace.setAdapter(placeAdapter);
lvPlace.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            lvPlace.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(myColors[0]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background of the list item when you click with `xml` also

First add `android:listSelector` to `listview`

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="4.0sp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"/>
```

Now create `list_row_selector.xml` in drawables

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_row_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

list_row_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>

<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
    android:endColor="#ffffff"
    android:angle="270" />
```

list_row_bg_hover.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
<gradient
    android:startColor="#18d7e5"
    android:centerColor="#16cedb"
    android:endColor="#09adb9"
    android:angle="270" />
```

Hope this will work for you..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can track the positions of your item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
            adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        // Change the background color of the selected element 
        //to your desire color
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work 100% correct. When I click on the first item, the items that are not visible now (but when you scroll down) will also turn blue. How can it be avoided?

Comment: You can do -> view.setSelecter(true); And add in  item xml android:state_selected="true"